# Algorithm for grouping names

Tags: algorithm, grouping

What's a good way to group this list of names:

```
Doctor Watson.
Dr. John Watson.
Dr. J Watson.
Watson.
J Watson.
Sherlock.
Mr. Holmes.
S Holmes.
Holmes.
Sherlock Holmes.
```

Into a grouped list of unique and complete names:

```
Dr. John Watson.
Mr. Sherlock Holmes.
```

Also interesting:

```
Mr Watson
Watson
Mrs Watson
Watson
John Watson
```

Since the algorithm doesn't need to make inferences about whether the first Watson is a Mr (likely) or Mrs but only group them uniquely, the only problem here is that John Watson obviously belongs to Mr and not Mrs Watson. Without a dictionary of given names for each gender, this can't be deduced.

So far I've thought of iterating through the list and checking each item with the remaining items. At each match, you group and start from the beginning again, and on the first pass where no grouping occurs you stop.

Here's some rough (and still untested) Python. You'd call it with a list of names.

```
def groupedNames(ns):
    if len(ns) > 1:
        # First item is query, rest are target names to try matching
        q = ns[0]
        # For storing unmatched names, passed on later
        unmatched = []
        for i in range(1,len(ns)):
            t = ts[i]
            if areMatchingNames(q,t):
                # groupNames() groups two names into one, retaining all info
                return groupedNames( [groupNames(q,t)] + unmatched + ns[i+1:] )
            else:
                unmatched.append(t)
    # When matching is finished
    return ns
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your names are always of the form `[honorific][first name or initial]LastName`, then you can start by extracting and sorting by the last name. If some names have the form `LastName[,[honorific][first name or initial]]`, you can parse them and convert to the first form. Or, you might want to convert everything to some other form.

In any case, you put the names into some canonical form and then sort by last name. Your problem is greatly reduced. You can then sort by first name and honorific within a last name group and then go sequentially through them to extract the complete names from the fragments.

As you noted, there are some ambiguities that you'll have to resolve. For example, you might have:

```
John Watson
Jane Watson
Dr. J. Watson
```

There's not enough information to say which of the two (if either!) is the doctor. And, as you pointed out, without information about the gender of names, you can't resolve `Mr. J. Watson` or `Mrs. J. Watson`.

Comment: Nice suggestion, you can also get names like John which don't tell you if they're given names or surnames, so I'll probably need to compare them in a different way. I'm thinking of expanding initials into parts and partially matching a set of given names also

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using hashing here.
Define a hash function as interpreting the name as a base 26 number where a = 0 and z = 25
Now just hash the individual words. So

h(sherlock holmes) = h(sherlock) + h(holmes) = h(holmes) + h(sherlock).

Using this you can easily identify names like:

John Watson and Watson John

For ambiguities like Dr. John Watson and Mr John Watson you can define the hash value for Mr and Dr to be the same.

To resolve conflicts like J. Watson and John Watson, you can just have just the first letter and the last name hashed. You can extend the idea for similar conflicts.